# PDFlib PHP linebreak in textflow

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I'm currently working on my first project with PDFlib and need to create a textflow which consists of multiple defined texts. But my problem is, that between those Texts there is no line breaking, the second text just starts right after the last word of the first one. There's not even a non-breaking space between the two words.

Here's an example out of my code:

```
// First Paragraph
    $optlist = "font=" . $fontRegular .
        " fontsize=10" .
        " fillcolor=black" .
        " wordspacing=0";
    $tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $firstParaqraph, $optlist);
    if ($tf == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    // Second Paragraph
    $optlist = "font=" . $fontRegular .
        " fontsize=10" .
        " fillcolor=black" .
        " wordspacing=0";
    $tf = $p->add_textflow($tf, $secondParaqraph, $optlist);
    if ($tf == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    do {
        $optlist = "blind=false";
        $result = $p->fit_textflow($tf, $x + 10, 0, $textStartHalf+60, $y, "");
    } while ($result == "_boxfull");
    if ($result == "_stop") {
        $infoHeight = $p->info_textflow($tf,'textheight');
        $count = $p->info_textflow($tf, 'boxlinecount');
        $y = $y - $infoHeight;
        $y = $y - ($infoHeight / $count);
    }
```

Maybe someone can help me with it, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Add a "\n" or "\r\n" at the end of a line. This will create a carriage return. Like so:
**$tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $firstParaqraph."\n\n", $optlist);**
OR
**$tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $firstParaqraph."\r\n\r\n", $optlist);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure now if my comment is ok or not but adding :

```php
$tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $firstParaqraph."\n\n", $optlist);

// or

$tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $firstParaqraph."\r\n\r\n", $optlist);
```

Example of what you need : https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/textflow/distance_between_paragraphs/php/

Comment: thanks again, this works fine for! Tbh I even overlooked this example in the Cookbook. I was just searching for "line break" in the documentation and looked at two other examples in the cookbook, but not this one... But your answer was really helpful!